# macOS zsh prints newline at end

Tags: shell, zsh

The following justifies the "[COW]" to the right, but also adds a newline.  I want to not have a newline so that the next thing printed is printed on the same line (but left-justified).  How do I do this?  All the docs I've seen say `printf` doesn't add a newline but if you double or triple the 2nd line below, it's obvious that it does

```
col=$(tput cols)
printf '%*s'  $col "[COW]"
printf "do you see that %s over there:" "cow"
```

NOTE: zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin20.0)

Comment: Is this really specific to `zsh`? Does it work as expected using `bash`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf` isn't adding a newline. The terminal emulator is scrolling because you wrote past the end of the line.

You should write a carriage return at the end of the first message, so it goes back to the beginning of the line.

```
col=$(tput cols)
printf '%*s\r'  $col "[COW]"
printf "do you see that %s over there:" "cow"
```

Comment: That doesn't work as listed.  I found that if I replace the third line with `echo "something"` then it works perfectly, but `printf` shows on the same line, but "[COW]" on the right is simply eliminated

Comment: Also weirdly with the following (3rd) line being `printf` then the last character is a `%`

Comment: It worked for me. Note that your shell prompt will be printed after the last line of output, without a newline before it. That might overwrite `[COW]` on the right.